# Why do programmers use `Acme` as a package, namespace or directory name

Tags: object-oriented, programming-practices

This may or may not be a silly question, but I really would like to know the answer to something which has been bothering me for a while.

I quite often see programming examples/conventions where the programmer has created a directory called `acme` to put stuff in.

What does `Acme` mean? Why Acme and not Emca or other?

Is Acme like a generic folder name to group miscellaneous OOP classes?

Where did the term come from in terms of the programming convention. As far as I can see, it has nothing to do with a programmer UI http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/acme.html

Comment: Also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acme_Corporation

Comment: Well this question makes me feel old.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is (ultimately) a question about English (acme is not constrained to programing), but is too old to migrate.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It's from [Road Runner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acme_Corporation). The Coyote always orders his traps/weapons from Acme and they all mysteriously backfire. It's since become the defacto namespace for gag packages.

[image]

Comment: Also perl's cpan: http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Acme&mode=all

Comment: @MichaelT Yep, and Pypi and Hackage as well I believe. It's just used for silly fun libraries

Comment: In my country we use "pippo", italian translation for Goofy

Comment: The use of ACME as fictional companyname predates roadrunner. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acme_Corporation

Comment: Interesting!!! I always assumed it was just a generic one size fits all / miscellaneous folder. e.g. a package for something which was still in development prior to refactoring / organising, or for testing purposes. No idea why they used Acme though. Now it makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: As I understood it stands for "A Company that Makes Everything"

Comment: I also read it as "American (who else ...) Company that Manfactures Everything" - anyway, the idea behind is the same. There is also an catalogue web site out there, featuring all the fancy stuff from the Toons (including the infamous "earthquake pills" http://home.roadrunner.com/~tuco/looney/acme/earth.html).